# How do I run SQL query on vb.net program inside PHC?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm trying to set a button on PHC to run a SQL query, but the program is on vb.net!
Anyone knows how to do it?

My query is simple has:

```
UPDATE cl SET INACTIVO='1' WHERE cl.clstamp='#STAMP#'
```

I just cant run it via vb.net which is mandatory by the field.

ty in advance

Comment: Whats a PHC? There's examples all over the web on running SQL from VB.NEt. Whats the actual problem - you don't know what code to use?

Comment: I figured it out.
Ty anyway.

my problem was that inside PHC (wich is a software for entreprise service) we have fields to program with VB and i needed to call a SQL query inside that VB field, just didnt know how to do it.

Comment: Nick, you can learn about PHC here: http://en.phcfx.com/
its a nice software wich is evolving, at Portugal and around the world ;)

Comment: Can I suggest you post your comment as an answer and accept it?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who needs it too, here it is: 'declare string' dim mcTsql as string 'get the query on the string' mcTsql="UPDATE cl SET INACTIVO='1' WHERE cl.clstamp='#STAMP#' " 'call it with the correspondent function(in this case was updatedata, since i need to UPDATE a table)' webcontrollib.cdata.updatedata(mcTsql)